# How do you change an individual icon's size on the desktop for windows 7

Tags: windows, desktop, icons

Is it possible to change an icons size on the desktop individually? I have already tried using group methods such as <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and the scroll wheel but that just changes every icons size not the individual ones.

Answer (score 2):

No, in Windows all desktop icons have the same size. It's a global setting.

Comment: Thanks Torben, although you would of thought that Microsoft would have an application that would allow this.

Comment: @shortyhi why would you think that? No OS as i recall has done this historically, although certain newer shells for Linux do... But certain shells of linux also make it nearly impossible to use the desktop to store files at all...

Comment: Hack solution:   Use an icon builder or graphics software that exports `.ico` files, and create the icon much smaller than regular size on a large canvas (e.g. Create a 256x256 canvas and center a 32x32 icon in the center).  Include a border that is almost transparent around the large canvas so that windows is forced to render it properly (otherwise it may try and scale just the part of the image that isn't transparent).